# If NULL or meets condition then continue in R

Tags: r, if-statement, null

I want to check if x is NULL/NA/NAN and if it is, then carry out the function. I also want to carry out the function if x is not between a min and a max number.

If I do:

```
#Checks if blank
isnothing <-  function(x) {
  any(is.null(x))  || any(is.na(x))  || any(is.nan(x)) 
}


x <- as.numeric(NULL)
min <- 25
max <- 45

#Actual function
if (isnothing(x) | !between(x,min,max)) {
    #Do something
}
```

I get the dreaded "argument is of length zero in if statement" error in R

I also tried:

```
x <- as.numeric(NULL)
min <- 25
max <- 45

if (isnothing(x) |(!isnothing(x) & !between(x,min,max))) {
    #Do something
}
```

This still doesn't work

**----------[EDIT]---------**

Thanks to the answer below, I have the below:

```
#Checks if blank
isnothing <-  function(x) {
  any(is.null(x),is.na(x),is.nan(x))
}

y <- NULL
x <- as.numeric(y)
min <- 25
max <- 45

if (any(isnothing(y), !between(x,min,max))) {
  print("Yep")
}else{
  print("Nope")
}
```

Which outputs "Yep"

It works but looks messy.

Comment: Use `any(is.null(x),is.na(x),is.nan(x))`? If you use `||`, then `any` maybe less useful or redundant.

Comment: What do you expect to do with the `between` though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined the function and used `all` and `any`. Better ways may exist:

```
isnothing <-  function(x,min, max) {
   if (all(any(is.null(x), is.na(x), is.nan(x)), between(x,min,max))) {
     print("Yep")
   }
   else{
     print("Nope")
   }

 }
 isnothing(x,min,max)
[1] "Nope"
```

A variant to the above:

```
isnothing <-  function(x,min, max) {
   if (!any(is.null(x), is.na(x), is.nan(x))){
     if(all(between(x,min,max))) {
     print("X is between min and max")
     }
     else{
       print("X is not between min and max")
     }
   }
  else{
     print("X is null, nan or NA")
   }
   }
 isnothing(x,min,max)
[1] "X is between min and max"
 isnothing(NULL,min,max)
[1] "X is null, nan or NA"
 isnothing(55,min,max)
[1] "X is not between min and max"
```

Comment: Works for me: `x <- NULL isnothing(x,min,max)
[1] "X is null, nan or NA"`

Comment: never mind, didn't see your edit. I want to execute the same code if it is null or not between those values ideally. So I want it to go to the same code block. I guess I could have an "valid" flag and get it to run in another if statement below "if (valid) {#Do something}

Comment: Could you add a sample of your expected result? In the example x is numeric and not NULL. As for the valid flag, how do we define valid?

Comment: Never mind! Just looked at my code and NULL isn't an issue sorry. it will always be numeric. All NULL's are coerced into numeric before too

Comment: Please edit the question to give a more general example and what result you expect with it.

Comment: @Pythonner12 Please check the edit based on your edit(I prefer the second code style hence edited that).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. i've edited again. I start with a variable y, I then apply an "as.numeric" earlier in the code to get x. as.numeric(NULL) gave numeric(0) which was giving issues. Testing y directly seems to work. Just looks a little messy

Comment: Only reason I haven't edited isnothing() is because I use it elsewhere in the codebase